# multiple "Deploy to Bluemix" buttons for one git repository

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

If I have a sinle git repository with multiple apps in it, is it possible to create a "Deploy to Bluemix" button for each app?

Instead of IBM Dev Ops services cloning the repository URL and creating the app from that, I really need it to clone and then change to a sub-directory. Maybe the button would be a link to something like this, but I don't see any parameters besides "repository" documented anywhere though.

```
https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=<repo url>&path=<app sub-directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking isn't possible at the moment.  You can deploy multiple services if they are declared within a manifest, but there is currently no way to pick and choose what would get deployed and what would not.